# Meteor.js doesn't load content of lib folder

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm new to `meteor.js`.

I started a new app using `meteor create textcircle`. I then added a package using `meteor add edemaine:sharejs-codemirror`

The problem is, in my app directory, I created a folder, `lib`, then a file `lib/collections.js`. Inside `lib/collections.js` I have this single line `console.log('Lib folder loaded')`. But I don't see the text on the console. Not in google chrome console, neither in my terminal. This shows that the file is clearly not loaded. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

`meteor --version` outputs `Meteor 1.8`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to import your files in client oder server main.js.

Lets assume you have also a folder named client.

inside that folder there is a file main.js.

`import '../lib/collections.js';`

Now your browsers console should show up the log.

If you have also a folder server and inside a file main.js

`import '../lib/collections.js';`

You will see the log also on your meteors console log.

Hope that helps
Tom

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was introduced to `meteor` via a coursera course that used an older version where you don't have to do all of those imports. I was wondering why `client/main.js` had to have `import ./main.html` Now I'm clear on all of that.

Comment: I've never had to do this before. In an older meteor project I just put files in /lib or /collection without having to worry about importing them to main.js. Is there some package that used to do this but is not installed as default any longer?

Comment: No, it is nothing special to meteor but ES6 features from nodejs. For that you have to write it in case of node's release. Maybe helpful link: https://adrianmejia.com/getting-started-with-node-js-modules-require-exports-imports-npm-and-beyond/